# Django: filter out few fields from json response

Tags: python, django

First of all, I'm very new to Django world, there could be a similar question, however i did not find a satisfactory answer.

Here is my scenario, i have few external REST endpoints, which I will hit from my Django app and get say 100-key JSON response. Now, when I'm writing my API in Django app, this response i'll have to trim and send it to outer world. Say for example,
My API is,

```
GET /api/profiles/1472
```

which will give user profile with id 1472. Now, this API will inturn call some other REST endpoint and fetch actual profile's data. So, in a way I'm writing a proxy endpoint. This proxy endpoint is supposed to trim out some fields and give it back to caller.

I've not written model classes for this.

What are best ways to achieve this in Django?

Edit 1:
Sample view will be like this,

```
class GetCompetitorProductsView(APIView):
    """
    Get Competitor products view
    """

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # I'll be having a list of fields to be trimmed from response.
        # It will be separate for every API.
        data = request.data

        error_checks = system_errors.check_for_competitor_products_input_error(data)

        if not error_checks:
            response = call_to_rest(data)
            return Response(response)
        else :
            return Response(error_checks, status = status.HTTP_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED)
```

And one more thing, same behavior is applied to all other APIs. So, I need  more generic solution which can be easily applied to other APIs.

Comment: You don't need model for this. Show us your view

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev added a sample view. As, I mentioned, I need more generic solution which can be easily applied to other APIs. Keep in mind, I'll have a list of fields to be trimmed for each API.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is how to filter in python

```
 allowed_fields = ("first_name", "last_name", "email")
 user_info = call_rest_endpoint(id=1472)
 result = {key:value for key,value in user_info.items() if key in allowed_fields}
```

First line define what fields u want to return.

Second line call the endpoint and get the data from theird party API.

Third line consist of 3 statements.

1. `user_info.items()` convert dictionary into array key/values paris.
2. Build dictionary from these tuples
3. but only if the key was found in allowed_fields tuple

Comment: Thanks @Ramast. I don't want to write same code again & again for each API.

Answer (score 0):

You can create function or mixin that you will put in parents of your view and then use it method for trimming. Here is example

```
class TrimDataMixin(object):
    ALLOWED_FIELDS = None

    def trim_data(self, data):
        allowed_fields = self.ALLOWED_FIELDS or []
        return {k: v for k, v in data.items() if k in allowed_fields}


class GetCompetitorProductsView(TrimDataMixin, APIView):
    """
    Get Competitor products view
    """
    ALLOWED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # I'll be having a list of fields to be trimmed from response.
        # It will be separate for every API.
        data = request.data

        error_checks = system_errors.check_for_competitor_products_input_error(data)

        if not error_checks:
            response = call_to_rest(data)
            # trim data            
            response = self.trim_data(response)
            return Response(response)
        else:
            return Response(error_checks, status = status.HTTP_412_PRECONDITION_FAILED)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does Django has some filter / serializer way to do the same? Probably more cleaner way??

Comment: @AashishP You can do this with serializers. But you will have to write similar things manually. There is few ways to do this, but how clean they will be depend on how you are writing your views. For example if all of your views has same `post` methods. You can move this method to `TrimDataMixin`, and customize this `post` with class variables like i did with `ALLOWED_FIELDS`